# Use JavaScript libraries inside of Gruntfile

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm new to Grunt and I'm trying to use the grunt-bower-concat node module to concat all my bower components into a single js file and css file respectively.  It's working great, except that I want to force grunt-bower-concat to use the minified versions of my bower components instead of the uncompressed versions.

Luckily, it comes with a [callback feature](https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-bower-concat#callback) where I can customize this:

```
callback: function(mainFiles, component) {
  return _.map(mainFiles, function(filepath) {
    // Use minified files if available
    var min = filepath.replace(/\.js$/, '.min.js');
    return grunt.file.exists(min) ? min : filepath;
  });
}
```

And I added it to my Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        bower_concat: {
            all: {
                dest: "src/js/<%= pkg.name %>-bower.js",
                cssDest: "src/css/<%= pkg.name %>-bower.css",
                callback: function(mainFiles) {
                    return _.map(mainFiles, function(filepath) {
                        var min = filepath.replace(/\.js$/, '.min.js');
                        return grunt.file.exists(min) ? min : filepath;
                    });
                }
            }
        },
...
```

And it fails with the following error:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/grunt --gruntfile /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/proj/Gruntfile.js bower_concat
Running "bower_concat:all" (bower_concat) task
Fatal error: _ is not defined
Process finished with exit code 3
```

This example is trying to use [underscore's map function](http://underscorejs.org/#map) and it's clear Grunt does not have access to this library.

How can I load underscore or use it's functions inside of my Gruntfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like you required underscore anywhere, unless you're not showing the whole file.

Any file in which you want to use underscore you need to do:

`var _ = require('underscore');`

before making use of _.

Oh, and of course you need to `npm install underscore --save` in the folder the gruntfile is in as well, to have the library there.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of requiring an extra library, simply replace

```
return _.map(mainFiles, function(filepath) {
```

With this:

```
return mainFiles.map(function(filepath) {
```

Comment: This is true, in that it helps him use `.map`, but it doesn't answer the question as to how he can load or use Underscores' features; this is relying on a native array feature.

Comment: @Paul I assumed he asked that question because he wasn't aware that underscore wasn't required to map an array.

Comment: That's fair, and your response certainly met his need, if not his explicit question.